# Adding attributes to the root xml stream

Tags: bean-io

Tried to look around for solutions but could not find any easy way to add attributes to root xml tag in beanIO 1.2.

I need to implement something like below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                <MyRootNode clientCode="German" recordCount="1">
                    <referrals> 
                        <Individual>
                            <indvId>50853</indvId>          
                            <firstName>Dad</firstName>
                            <middleName/>
                            <lastName>Test</lastName>
                            <suffixName/>
                            <gender>M</gender>
                            <race>WH</race>
                            <ethnicity>UN</ethnicity>
                            <DOB>2000-02-02</DOB>
                            <caseNumber>710645</caseNumber>
                        </Individual>       
                    </referrals>
                </MyRootNode>
```

As of now my beanio mapping file looks like :

```
<stream name="MyRootNode" format="xml">
                        <record name="referrals" class="example.test.TestBean">
                            <bean name="individual" class="example.test.Individual" xmlName="Individual">
                                <field name="indvId" />
                                <field name="firstName" minOccurs="1" />
                                <field name="middleName" minOccurs="1" />
                                <field name="lastName" minOccurs="1" />
                                <field name="suffixName" minOccurs="1" />
                                <field name="gender" minOccurs="1" />
                                <field name="race" minOccurs="1" />
                                <field name="ethnicity" minOccurs="1" />
                                <field name="DOB" minOccurs="1" />
                                <field name="caseNumber" minOccurs="1" />
                            </bean>
                            </record>
                </stream>
```

Need to add  **`clientCode="German" recordCount="1"`**  to the MyRootNode.

Appreciate your help!

Thanks & Regards,
Rajiv

Comment: show us some code. What have you achieved yet? Why are you failing?

Comment: Using the BeanIO mapping file (contents provided above), I am able to generate XML (contents provided above), except the clientCode="German" recordCount="1" on the root tag. I need to know is there anything we can change in the mapping file to accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

With the following changes it should be possible to do it:

```
<stream format="xml" name="MyRootNode" xmlType="none">
    <record class="example.test.TestBean" name="MyRootNode">
        <field name="clientCode" xmlType="attribute"/>
        <field name="recordCount" xmlType="attribute"/>
        <segment name="referrals">
            <bean class="example.test.Individual" name="individual" xmlName="Individual">
                <field name="indvId"/>
                <field minOccurs="1" name="firstName"/>
                <field minOccurs="1" name="middleName"/>
                <field minOccurs="1" name="lastName"/>
                <field minOccurs="1" name="suffixName"/>
                <field minOccurs="1" name="gender"/>
                <field minOccurs="1" name="race"/>
                <field minOccurs="1" name="ethnicity"/>
                <field minOccurs="1" name="DOB"/>
                <field minOccurs="1" name="caseNumber"/>
            </bean>
        </segment>
    </record>
</stream>
```

Explanation:

- The stream is not generated as an XML Element anymore
- The first record element is now the "MyRootNode" and it has the attributes added